# Xamarin.Forms embbeded image not stretching properly

Tags: c#, ios, image, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a couple embedded images in my Xamarin.Forms Application.

Most of them were in platform specific folders. I am trying to bring them back to embedded images for the sake of simplicity and maintenance.

Here is my xaml:
Before:

```
     <Image  Source="RJ45-Pinout-T568A-4.jpg" />
```

After (2 diffrent attemps):

```
     <Image Source="{local:ImageResource ApplicationCalcul.RJ45-Pinout-T568A-4.jpg}" Aspect="AspectFill" />
     <Image Source="{local:ImageResource ApplicationCalcul.RJ45-Pinout-T568A-4.jpg}" />
```

But someow I can't manage to get the same result.

Before the image would stretch to the side of the screen and keep the good aspect ratio.

Now I get either a small image or a image that only stretches horizontally or an image that is cut on the top and bottom.

[image: Top oone is from IOS file secondwith AspectFill and last with no addtional property]

1. First image in screenshot is the image like before.(in ios project)
2. Second image was stretched to good with but cut out top and bottom
3. Third image we can only see partially but it didn't stretch at all but is too small although the aspect ration is good.

Comment: 1. Have you tried Aspect="AspectFit". 2. Have you put your images in a scrollable container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First image in screenshot is the image like before.(in ios project)

If using

`<Image Source="RJ45-Pinout-T568A-4.jpg"/>`

the size of Image will be large and set `Aspect` default as `AspectFit`.

> Third image we can only see partially but it didn't stretch at all but is too small although the aspect ration is good.

And if using

`<Image Source="{local:ImageResource ApplicationCalcul.RJ45-Pinout-T568A-4.jpg}" />`

the szie of Image will be small, and also set `Aspect` default as `AspectFit`.

> Second image was stretched to good with but cut out top and bottom

About **[Aspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.aspect?view=xamarin-forms)**, you could have a look at following screenshot:

[image]

Then if using `Aspect="AspectFill"`, image will be cut out and bottom.

For example, the **Xaml** code as follows:

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Image Embedded Resource XAML" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Label Text="Image Embedded Resource XAML" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <!-- uses a custom Extension defined in this project for now -->
        <Image Source="Tree.png" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
        <Image Source="{local:ImageResource WorkingWithImages.Tree.png}" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
        <Image Source="{local:ImageResource WorkingWithImages.Tree.png}" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Aspect="AspectFill" />
        <Image Source="{local:ImageResource WorkingWithImages.Tree.png}" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        <Image Source="{local:ImageResource WorkingWithImages.Tree.png}" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Aspect="Fill" />
        <Label Text="This image is an embedded resource, referenced in XAML. The same image file is used, regardless of the pixel density of the device (eg. iOS Retina)." />
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The effect is:

[image]

============================Update================================

> Is there a way of making the tree the width of the phone and also make the tree image height the same as the width of the phone?

You could set a `HeightRequest` and `Aspect="Fill"` for **Image**, no matter using `Source="RJ45-Pinout-T568A-4.jpg"` or S`ource="{local:ImageResource ApplicationCalcul.RJ45-Pinout-T568A-4.jpg}"`, it will work.

For example, the Xaml code as follows:

```
<Image Source="Tree.png" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HeightRequest="300" Aspect="Fill" />
<Image Source="{local:ImageResource WorkingWithImages.Tree.png}" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HeightRequest="300" Aspect="Fill" />
```

The effect:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what my problem is. Is there a way of making the tree the width of the phone and also make the tree image height the same as the width of the phone?

Comment: @user3704628 If you need to make that, you need to set `HeightRequest` and `Aspect="Fill"` for **Image**. I have updated the answer, you could have a look at that when you have time. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help, sorry for beeing picky but this solution gives me a rectangular image as the with depends on the device running the app I guess. Is there a way of making sure the ration width/height stays the same as original picture? I.e. if square image then image stays square. I guess I should resize in code behind after the app is done rendering?

Comment: Solution I found is : Aspect="Fill"   AND                                                              private void ContentPage_LayoutChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            img1.HeightRequest = img1.Width;
        }